# android Listviewのスクリーン外のアイテムへの参照を取得する方法

Tags: android

listViewのアイテムが10個スクリーンに表示されていて、11個目がスクリーン外にあるとします。11個すべてのデータを取得したいのですが、11個目のデータへの参照の取り方がわかりません。
以下のコードを実行すると11個目の参照を得ようとしたときにnull pointer exceptionがでてしまいます。

```
public void saveData() {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    int count = listView.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View child = listView.getChildAt(i);
        TextView setText1 = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
        EditText text = (EditText) child.findViewById(R.id.setText1);
        String content1 = setText1.getText().toString().trim();
        String content2 = text.getText().toString().trim();
        buffer.append(content1);
        buffer.append(",");
        buffer.append(content2);
        buffer.append(",");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> num_set) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_row, num_set);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View CustomView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);


        String[] num = getItem(position).split(",");
        TextView setText1 = (TextView) CustomView.findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
        EditText setText2 = (EditText) CustomView.findViewById(R.id.setText2);

        setText1.setText(num[0]);
        setText2.setText(num[1]);
        return CustomView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ListView`からデータを取得するのではなく、`Adapter`からデータを取得しましょう。ここでは`CustomAdapter`を使用していると仮定します。

```
public void saveData() {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter)listView.getAdapter();
    for(int i = 0, length = adapter.getCount(); i < length; i++) {
        String[] rowData = adapter.getItem(i).split(",");
        buffer.append(String.format("%s,%s,", rowData[0].trim(), rowData[1].trim()));
    }
}
```